# MongoDB Aggregation: Calculate differences between array elements or distances

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my database, I have locations of an object at different time. I would like to use aggregation to calculate the total traveled distance.

Below is a sample for the data. "minutes" and "seconds" fields provide the time of the location. "location" field has the x and y coordinate of the object. How can I calculate the traveled distance between every two points then sum the total traveled distance?

```
{ 
    "_id" : 0,
    "locations" : [ 
                    { "minutes" : 43, "seconds" : 39,, "location" : [ 7.177781171570082, 8.39005423150688 ] },
                    { "minutes" : 43, "seconds" : 41, "location" : [ 13.239988410746804, 6.369708832879012 ] },
                    { "minutes" : 43, "seconds" : 51, "location" : [ 12.647876477258006, 6.288597609113424 ] },
                    { "minutes" : 43, "seconds" : 55, "location" : [ 12.662746868281697, 6.296370768057626 ] },
                    { "minutes" : 44, "seconds" : 38, "location" : [ 12.5326309468244, 6.308199488190107 ] },
                    { "minutes" : 44, "seconds" : 43, "location" : [ 12.53972817890389, 6.308199488190107 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 44, "seconds" : 53, "location" : [ 12.530265202797903, 6.310565232216604 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 44, "seconds" : 58, "location" : [ 12.527899458771406, 6.315296720269597 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 45, "seconds" : 31, "location" : [ 12.546825410983377, 6.315296720269597 ] },
                    { "minutes" : 45, "seconds" : 36, "location" : [ 12.542093922930384, 6.3129309762431 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 45, "seconds" : 45, "location" : [ 12.530265202797903, 6.3555143687200335 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 45, "seconds" : 40, "location" : [ 12.527899458771406, 6.341319904561056 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 45, "seconds" : 50, "location" : [ 12.536235756046255, 6.350367881600166 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 45, "seconds" : 59, "location" : [ 12.530265202797903, 6.327125440402078 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 45, "seconds" : 55, "location" : [ 12.546032231499275, 6.348017098292042 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 46, "seconds" : 14, "location" : [ 12.536573712767805, 6.3314498270318005 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 46, "seconds" : 18, "location" : [ 12.53972817890389, 6.3673430888525155 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 46, "seconds" : 23, "location" : [ 12.536525552897315, 6.364920756128036 ] }, 
                    { "minutes" : 46, "seconds" : 33, "location" : [ 11.969583868518272, 6.426486689514924 ] } 
                ]

}
```

Comment: `$range`? (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) But I have no idea, how you'll transform your: `Y,X` coordinates in distance between points,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "info":{
                $reduce:{
                    "input":{
                        $slice:["$locations",1, {$size:"$locations"}]
                    },
                    "initialValue":{
                        "totalDistance":0,
                        "co-ordinates":{
                            $let:{
                                "vars":{
                                    "firstLocation":{
                                        $arrayElemAt:["$locations",0]
                                    }
                                },
                                "in":{
                                    "x":{
                                        $arrayElemAt:["$$firstLocation.location",0]
                                    },
                                    "y":{
                                        $arrayElemAt:["$$firstLocation.location",1]  
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "in":{
                        "totalDistance":{
                            $sum:[
                                "$$value.totalDistance",
                                {
                                    $sqrt:{
                                        $sum:[
                                            {
                                                $pow:[
                                                    {
                                                        $subtract:[
                                                            {
                                                               $arrayElemAt:["$$this.location",0] 
                                                            },
                                                            "$$value.co-ordinates.x"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    2
                                                ]
                                            },
                                             {
                                                $pow:[
                                                    {
                                                        $subtract:[
                                                            {
                                                               $arrayElemAt:["$$this.location",1] 
                                                            },
                                                            "$$value.co-ordinates.y"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    2
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "co-ordinates":{
                            "x":{
                                $arrayElemAt:["$$this.location",0] 
                            },
                            "y":{
                                $arrayElemAt:["$$this.location",1] 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "totalDistance":"$info.totalDistance"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "locations" : [
        {
            "minutes" : 43,
            "seconds" : 39,
            "location" : [
                7.177781171570082,
                8.39005423150688
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 43,
            "seconds" : 41,
            "location" : [
                13.239988410746804,
                6.369708832879012
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 43,
            "seconds" : 51,
            "location" : [
                12.647876477258006,
                6.288597609113424
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 43,
            "seconds" : 55,
            "location" : [
                12.662746868281697,
                6.296370768057626
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 44,
            "seconds" : 38,
            "location" : [
                12.5326309468244,
                6.308199488190107
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 44,
            "seconds" : 43,
            "location" : [
                12.53972817890389,
                6.308199488190107
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 44,
            "seconds" : 53,
            "location" : [
                12.530265202797903,
                6.310565232216604
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 44,
            "seconds" : 58,
            "location" : [
                12.527899458771406,
                6.315296720269597
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 45,
            "seconds" : 31,
            "location" : [
                12.546825410983377,
                6.315296720269597
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 45,
            "seconds" : 36,
            "location" : [
                12.542093922930384,
                6.3129309762431
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 45,
            "seconds" : 45,
            "location" : [
                12.530265202797903,
                6.3555143687200335
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 45,
            "seconds" : 40,
            "location" : [
                12.527899458771406,
                6.341319904561056
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 45,
            "seconds" : 50,
            "location" : [
                12.536235756046255,
                6.350367881600166
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 45,
            "seconds" : 59,
            "location" : [
                12.530265202797903,
                6.327125440402078
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 45,
            "seconds" : 55,
            "location" : [
                12.546032231499275,
                6.348017098292042
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 46,
            "seconds" : 14,
            "location" : [
                12.536573712767805,
                6.3314498270318005
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 46,
            "seconds" : 18,
            "location" : [
                12.53972817890389,
                6.3673430888525155
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 46,
            "seconds" : 23,
            "location" : [
                12.536525552897315,
                6.364920756128036
            ]
        },
        {
            "minutes" : 46,
            "seconds" : 33,
            "location" : [
                11.969583868518272,
                6.426486689514924
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "totalDistance" : 7.931893594924767 }
```

**Explanation:** We are using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to sum up travelled distance between each points. The distance between two points is calculated using the following 
formulae:

```
           _______________________
Distance: √(x2−x1)^2 + (y2−y1)^2
```